# What do you mean by drawing an image in Qt/QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qpainter.html#drawImage-5

`void QPainter::drawImage(const QRect &rectangle, const QImage &image)`

> Draws the given image into the given rectangle.

They have used the word draw for a reason. I believe if I have an image I can myself put it in a rectangle. I don't need a specialized function for that.

What does this function do besides putting the image in the rectangle?

Is it somehow more efficient than the following?

```
Rectangle
{
   height: 100; width: 100
   Image
   {
      source: "xyz.png"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** You are confusing concepts: QImage is not the same as QML Image item, and similar for QRect and Rectangle.

**Long answer:**

QImage is a class that allows to represent an image, in simple words it is a container of the bytes that represent the image and how those bytes are related. Instead Image is an Item that allows displaying an image.

QPainter's drawImage method paints a rectangle over a QImage (changes a few bytes to represent the rectangle). Instead in your code you are creating an Item Rectangle where you place an Item Image.

Facts:

- QImage and QRect are not visual elements
- QImage can be taken as a base for painting a visual element.
- QPainter is used for low level painting unlike QML items (Items are painted using QPainter)

Comment: So, this argument: `const QImage &image` is not the path of any existing png. It is supposed to be group of bytes?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl It is a group of bytes + the format (RGB, RGBA, etc) + size

Comment: Please give me one example where we would need to use the group of bytes rather than an existing image. Thank you.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl If you want to create an image(png) using information from the GUI